# Using Azure DevOps release unable to run vsts2017 web tests in azure CI pipeline

Tags: performance

I have created a continuous integration in dev.azure pipeline. I have created a build>>release>> added Agent as VSTS Test Platform Installer >> added Visual Studio Test runner which will use vstest.console.exe to execute webtests.

I have a solution>project>webtest scripts and supported files which i ran locally successfully in Visual Studio 2017. Now i am trying to move these web tests to pipeline such that i can run them as CI.

I have added everything as below in dev azure pipeline:

1. Added Visual Studio Test Platform Installer.  vsTestVersion: 15.0
2. Configured assembly test files as ***test*.dll
   ***.WebTests
   ***.testsettings.
3. Search folder as: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_Performance/drop/
   Version as: Visual Studio 2017
4. Settings file as: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_Performance/drop/Local.testsettings
5. Build platform: AnyCPU and rest settings as runInParallel: false
   codeCoverageEnabled: true
   testRunTitle: 'LoadTest_$(rev:r)'
   platform: AnyCPU
   configuration: Release
   continueOnError: true

Now when i am saving my release and running it. It runs the whole solution and copy all files successfully in the virtual drive under D:\a\r1\a_Performance\drop

But as a next step once the test runs after VSTS Installer it shows.......................................
............
No test is available in D:\a\r1\a_Performance\drop\WebAndLoadTestProject1\bin\Release\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.WebTestFramework.dll D:\a\r1\a_Performance\drop\WebAndLoadTestProject1\bin\Release\WebAndLoadTestProject1.dll. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.
2019-03-04T20:37:35.7477518Z 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZ4ZP.png)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a quick solution. Convert the .webtest file to a code test file and checkin that code in git. Run the same solution now in azure DevOps release. It is running the same test successfully in the assigned vsts2017 VM. So as per my understanding it seems Visual Studio webtests cannot run directly in pipeline release.

To convert the webtests into code open the vsts webtest on the toolbar and there is a Generate Code button in bottle shape. Clicking this button prompts for a test name, and then generates code of the same webtest. Both the webtest and code are separate from each other. Changes in one will not added into other.